# No connection to Router(Lan,Wan) after installing AVG 2016 and/or Updating windows

Tags: windows-7, installation, internet, connection, avg-antivirus

Well..i know there have been questions like this one all over su but none have an actual solution.. so ill just give a cleaner explanation of what i did and how i did it..

Installed clean w7 Ultimate x64 on my system last night and decided to try ClamWin and Sentinel for a few hours..Though i liked the minimal resource hook and interaction of the two,i have enough resources to run AVG even on a HDD(as opposed to SSD which gives u a NULL experience of hooks) and so i Updated Windows (177 updates at the time,all optional Net.Framework and security updates as i have dev key to windows7).After installing the windows updates i installed AVG 2016 and entered the key to upgrade to a licensed version..No more than 40-50% of the install,i lost my internet(lan) connection,my android wifi connection and everyone in the house lost their wifi also(towards the router on Lan1 with the station that i installed AVG on)...Only tried uninstalling and installing over and over again...(as im writting this,im installing again) Will try answer that says to uncheck network settings that involve AVG!

Comment: Disable AVG's capability to spy on your HTTPS traffic and you likely will solve you problem.

Comment: I can't imagine how installing AVG on your computer would take out every wireless connection on the network ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - I can't.  Which tells me multiple things are going on.  Of course I think AVG is the worst program every created because of a personal experience I have with it.  So I might not be the best person to even read this question, because my immediate thought, is blame AVG for the problems because ( honestly it likely is the reason ).

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, agreed. I replaced it with Avast a good few years ago ;)

Comment: Well i would give up on AVG if it wasnt the best interactive AV with a good UI...Haven't used Avast ever,back in the old days i had a kaspersky but at the time resources it needed were galactic compared to my 512 ram haha!!

Answer (score 0):

Took time and reading but it did happen!

> I can't imagine how installing AVG on your computer would take out every wireless connection on the network

Who could ever imagine something like that happening...But also who could think about a network filter breaching so hard into the system that it actually blocks traffic from and to the router (since i have admin rights/telnet/webUI for the router on C:/)

**The Answer/Solution**
Network And Sharing Center > Open all/selected/current connection properties and **DE**select Avg Network Filter > Wait for Connections/Adapters to become responsive again and **Restart Pc**

Problem Solved !!